# How does ScriptProperties work?

Tags: google-apps-script

I want to use ScriptProperties but it gives me a page error.  My entire script won't run.
Is there something else that I need to do?

```
 if(ScriptProperties.getProperty('smnumCounter')== null)ScriptProperties.setProperty('smnumCounter','1');
  var smnumValue = parseInt(ScriptProperties.getProperty('smnumCounter'));
    smnumValue++;
    ScriptProperties.setProperty('smnumCounter', smnumValue.toString());

  var smnumValue2 = ScriptProperties.getProperty('smnumCounter');
```

Comment: You have any details about the error in the logs ?

Comment: Only this:

Google Docs has encountered a server error. If reloading the page doesn't help, please contact us.

To discuss this or other issues, visit the Google Docs Help forum. To see the list of known problems, check the Google Docs Known Issues page.


Sorry, and thanks for your help!
- The Google Docs Team

Answer (score 1):

You have a syntax error somewhere in the code.  This exact error occurs for me when I'm trying to add Ui Elements to the app, like `app.add(label);` when `label` is no longer a Ui Element.  (Code that I forgot to change/delete).  There's nothing wrong with your ScriptProperties code that I see.

Comment: But the error only happens when I add that block of code.  If I take it out, everything works.  Really strange.

Answer (score 0):

Your code works perfectly fine for me.

Comment: I put your sample into a function too : 
function scriptProp(){
  if(ScriptProperties.getProperty('smnumCounter')== null)
    ScriptProperties.setProperty('smnumCounter','1');
  var smnumValue = parseInt(ScriptProperties.getProperty('smnumCounter'));
  Browser.msgBox(smnumValue);
  smnumValue++;
  ScriptProperties.setProperty('smnumCounter', smnumValue.toString());
  
  var smnumValue2 = ScriptProperties.getProperty('smnumCounter'); 
  Browser.msgBox(smnumValue2);
}

Comment: Could you edit your first post and show us more of your code ?